# How to send multiple objects to webservice using CXF services with JSON

Tags: json, cxf

i have a webservice which accepts 3 different  types of object. i want to pass these objects using JSON........ and acccept the server side as JSON here i convert the objects into java objects.

can any one tell me the code.

My objects are Emploee, Student and cource.....

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Path("<some path here>")
public Response addBookJaxbJson(
    @Multipart(value = "employee", type = "application/json") Employee emp,
    @Multipart(value = "student", type = "application/json") Student student,
    @Multipart(value = "course", type = "application/json") Course course) 
    throws Exception {
}
```

And of course, your client will have to send multipart data, either from a form or constructed somehow.